# What type of npn /diode is this?

Tags: identification, npn, tester

I try to replace a sot 23 npn. The only markup is "NV" . It's used to switch a relay.

I tested it with two transistor tester. Both of them show me a diode with the npn symbol. I dont know why... a flywheel diode?

Is it important?
[image: pcb]
[image: tester]

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a [KRC246S](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://file.wlxmall.com/view%3Fid%3D2948762%26k%3D2b0fa5dfed9f96a7f94b3613fbce1936&ved=2ahUKEwj52I-PmNv1AhW1hP0HHYlyBssQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1Uz0IvjF2cWVaarEt0H0_w). The bias resistors might be throwing off your tester device.

Comment: Thank you. I tested the resistance and its the same as the datasheet. I will try it. Thank!